# Is there a constant time operation to determine whether a result object from a select statement has any rows?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using the sqlite dialect with sqlalchemy.  When I run the following script I see the file paths get printed out but for `result.lastrowid` and `result.rowcount` the values `None` and `-1` get printed respectively

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from create_database import files
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)

conn = engine.connect()
s = select([files.c.full_path, files.c.file_name])
result = conn.execute(s)

for row in result:
    print row[files.c.full_path]
print result.lastrowid
print result.rowcount
result.close()
```

Why are those methods returning `None` and `-1` when there are rows in the result set?

Is there a constant time operation to determine whether a SELECT statement returns no rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastrowid` is used only for `INSERT` statements; `rowcount` is used only for `UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements.

Result rows are computed dynamically; there is no function to check result rows without actually trying to fetch one.

You have to call `fetchone()` and check the result.
(This has the side effect that the first result row is already fetched, so the following code must not fetch again if it wants to read the first row.)